# How to get original host in django using proxy?

Tags: python, django, nginx, proxy

I use nginx proxy for a django application. And I want `request.META['HTTP_HOST']` parameter to get my real host. So I use `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST` setting parameter. But `request.META['HTTP_HOST']` still gets wrong value from proxy.

nginx

```
    location / {
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto   http;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host    $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server  $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_pass http://backend:8000;
    }
```

django settings

```
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

parts of `request.META` variable

```
'HTTP_HOST': 'backend:8000',
'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO': 'http',
'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST': 'localhost', 
'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER': 'localhost', 
'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '192.168.240.1'
```

Why `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST` setting doesn't work? I use Django 4.0.

Comment: Pass the actual Host header? - `proxy_set_header Host $host;`

Comment: @IainShelvington so, it works, but is it correct way to solve this problem and why django has `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST` setting? :-)

Comment: `request.META['HTTP_HOST']` just returns the value of the Host header, if you want it to equal the real host you have to set it in your proxy. The `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST` setting is used to tell Django to __not__ use that header to get the actual host, the method `request.get_host()` will resolve the host using the settings and headers available   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host